# Yii 2: Using module's image declared as asset

Tags: php, yii2, yii-modules

I have a image in a module within the following structure: **vendor/myvendorname/mymodulename/assets/img/delete-icon.png**

I need to add an `<img>` to the page via JavaScript, and it may have the `src` attribute pointing to that `delete-icon.png`.

```
$("#delete").attr("src", "?");
```

How can I reference the image if it will be put in an asset directory created by Yii? What is the way to get this path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you register the `AssetBundle` it is possible to fetch its `baseUrl`. In the rest of the view you can then use that to get to your images:

```
$assets = MyAssetBundle::register($this);
$imagePath = $assets->baseUrl . '/img/delete-icon.png';

$this->registerJS(<<<JS
   $("#delete").attr("src", "$imagePath");
JS
  );
```

Comment: What is you `register` your AssetBundle in the layout and need the baseUrl in the view?